# Android studio failed to instantiate one or more classes after update to SDK 26

Tags: java, android, xml, gradle

After downloading SDK 26 and updated my project I had some library conflicts which I successfully fixed. But I have this persistent issue that it is tackled nowhere in the forums or SO.

My XML preview is broken. I can build and run the program but I can't see anything because of that:

[image]

**I tried:**

1. Changing the theme from `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` to
   `Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`
2. [Updating my gradle in a similar way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43979180/6792992)
3. Invalidate Cache / Restart
4. Checked and updated all my libraries and removed all errors regarding gradle
5. Changed the api on the preview
6. All SDKs are updated.

Everything was fine right before I update to SDK 26. All the solutions available do nothing. Help would be very much appreciated

**EDIT**

my gradle.build

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "gr.softweb.sakouli"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile project(path: ':linkedin-sdk')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    //    configurations.all {
    //        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
    //            def requested = details.requested
    //            if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
    //                if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
    //                    details.useVersion '26.0.1'
    //                }
    //            }
    //        }
    //    }
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.ncapdevi:frag-nav:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
    compile 'co.lujun:androidtagview:1.1.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.braintreepayments.api:drop-in:3.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
```

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding the project?

Comment: Close Android Studio totally and open it again and see if problem is still there.

Comment: @Darush see 3rd point in the OP tried list :)

Comment: @Raghavendra I mean Go to File > Exit

Comment: Update your appcompat and design libraries to  com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1 and com.android.support:design:26.0.1' and see if it works

Comment: The most recent version is 26.0.2 according to this https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html. So try that as well.

Comment: @Darush i have rebuild it several times. I have already downloaded 26.0.1 and it is the initial version that i encountered the problem for first time. 26.0.2 indeed is the latest but in my SDK manager tools there is no option to download it, only reaches at 26.0.1

Comment: @StamatisStiliats I'm quite not sure but will u try by updating your android studio?

Comment: @Raghavendra my android studio is updated on the latest version already

Comment: @StamatisStiliats can u tell me the version?

Comment: current version : 2.3 - Android SDK tools : 26.0.2 ( i dont remember updating to that but what is what the info says)

Comment: I updated all the Components of Android Studio from help>check for updates and encountered the same error. What solved the problem in my case I have given the answer. Hope that solves yours too.

Comment: @StamatisStiliats If possible, post your code here or upload it on Github so I could try it in my Android Studio. I need to check your layout and the build.gradle files.

Comment: @Darush i edit my questioon with my build.gradle file. My code is not the issue since it was perfectly working before.

Comment: @StamatisStiliats put apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' outside of the dependencies and sync the project. I have posted my build.gradle file.

Comment: @StamatisStiliats also add compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

Comment: @Darush i am not using ConstraintLayout,so that made no difference. The error with the preview is occuring with every layout file in my project btw

Comment: @StamatisStiliats my bad. There seems to be a conflict between your dependencies. What if you shift your design and support libraries right below the androidTestCompile?

Comment: @Darush Doesn't make any difference. Truth is that some of the libraries are using lower versions but that was something android studio was informing me so i override them by compiling the specific versions i.e. `compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.0.0'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153950/discussion-between-stamatis-stiliats-and-darush).

Answer (score 1):

Updating the following:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
```

to the following solved the problem for me:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
```

Build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myandroidgoogleappengine"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.2.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: i tried it but unfortunatelly didn't work. Checking updates says that i have the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem .Just **updated** `26.0.0` **to** `26.0.0-alpha1` and the problem is solved.